# Launch Another IOS App from Xamarin Forms App

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to test if an app is present from MyApp (CanOpen). If so, I wish to open the app, otherwise I have an https address to open a webview. I am getting the false return on the can open test. I believe my code is sound but I am not sure on the info.plist. I have a url type (in info.plist) for MyApp. I have the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry for the other app (health), but unsure of how that reference is tied back to the actual app.... Any help is greatly appreciated:

**in MyApp PCL is the following Interface:**

```
   public interface IAppHandler
   {
       Task<bool> LaunchApp(string uri);
   }
```

**In the Model View where I making the deoendency call to the actual handler:**

```
    string appid = @"health://";
    var result = await DependencyService.Get<IAppHandler>().LaunchApp(appid);

    if (!result)
    {
        Show_WebView(url);
    }
```

**In the platform specific AppHandler:**

```
public Task<bool> LaunchApp(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var canOpen = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl(uri));
        if (!canOpen)
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        return Task.FromResult(UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(uri)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

**In the info.plist:**

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <string>com.apple.Health</string>
</array>  
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
    <string>health</string>
 </array>
```

Comment: you need to register the URLScheme of the app you want to open.

Comment: Shabir, using the bundle id?  thanks

Comment: I am missing how to tie the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to the URL Types.

Comment: no bundle id is different, you need to register the Custom URL scheme of another app you want to open

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the URL Scheme of the target app into the info.plist file in order to use `canOpen` functionality. i.e
[image]

Comment: Is roomreservation the name you are using in the OpenApp statement? What is accom.ibm-cognos-mobile?

Comment: both are URL schemes of the 2 different apps

Comment: what value you are passing in uri?

Comment: I have tried a few different things but right now I am using health

Comment: <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>accom.ibm.cognos-mobile</string>
  <string>roomreservation</string>
 </array>

Comment: No you need to pass the URL scheme but if health is the URL scheme of that app than its fine.

Comment: what I don;t understand is how health relates to the actual app that I am trying to open. I apologize for not seeing this clearer.

Comment: How dod I determine the URL scheme of the other app. It was not developed by my team

Comment: You can actually find yourself, download the app in your laptop, click to rename and add .zip in the end, than unzip it , and see all the .plist file and check for Custom URL Scheme in that. If there is any available you can use that for opening that app.

Comment: Thank you. My last question is will it work in the simulator?

Comment: If you have both that app installed  in the simulator than it will work.